# Cannot connect laptop to TV via HDMI

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi

My laptop is connected to TV via HDMI. During installation of Ubuntu, the TV displayed the Ubuntu screen background and a few buttons on the top right corner of the screen.

However, after installation, the TV screen went blue. I tried System Settings ->  Display and I can see the TV screen is detected.

Appreciate any instructions on how to get this fixed. Thank you.

---

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 229mm
   1440x900      60.00*+
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x400       59.95  
   640x350       59.77  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1360x768      60.02 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      85.00    75.08    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       85.06    72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       85.01    75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94
```

---

I give up, looking for way to uninstall ubuntu. 
Ubuntu is probably not for me. While it does not require any effort connecting my laptop to TV via HDMI, it took me days without any comments, guidance here so I am going back to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the `xrandr` output it seems that no resolution is set for the TV.

Try to set one of the resolutions listed under HDMI-1 in the `xrandr` output. For example:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1360x768
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Fritz,

After setting the HDMI, it still not working. I restarted the laptop, nothing happen. So here is the new xrandr results,hoping you would be able to see what is still wrong.

```
xrandr
```

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192

LVDS-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 229mm

1440x900      60.00 +
   1152x864      59.96
   1024x768      59.92* 
   800x600       59.86
   640x480       59.38
   720x400       59.55
   640x400       59.95
   640x350       59.77
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
580mm x 320mm

1360x768      60.02 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x768      59.87
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      85.00    75.08    70.07    60.00* 
   800x600       85.06    72.19    75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       85.01    75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94